# Sending token dynamically

Tags: solidity, remix

```
uint h =10;
p.transfer(10 ether)
p.transfer(h ether);
```

The second line is working but I need to send token dynamically as in line 3, but it is showing an error. How can I resolve it?.
I am using 0.7.6 compiler(remix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
p.transfer(h ether);
```

To this:

```
p.transfer(h * 1 ether);
```

Or if you want to be on the safe side, to this:

```
if (h > 0) {
    uint value = h * 1 ether;
    require(value / h == 1 ether, "multiplication overflow");
    p.transfer(value);
}
```